# Extend system environment variables - Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables

In Windows 10, is it possible to combine/extend system environment variables with user environment variables? Similar to how `path` works?

I've seen this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/878382/469563) on another question, but it only described the default behaviour of having a system environment variable and a user environment variable with the same name.

My issue is I have a system environment variable with quite a few semi-colon separated values in, that occasionally changes and isn't controlled by me, but I need to add 2 values to the end of it to allow me to develop on my account. Ideally, I don't have to update my user one every time the system one changes but that is what I'm currently doing

Comment: Why don’t you create a new system variable and add it to your PATH variable? Keep in mind that system variables do have a maximum character length

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1385878/8672) and especially the part about "embedded environmental variables".